# Can we make a GET API call request which has multiple headers as a URL in browser

Tags: java, api, url, browser

I need to make a GET request from the browser to an API. It has multiple headers.
it is something like this.

```
URL= http://192.168.2.21:8081/something/something
Header= workspace: abcdefgh
Header= Authorization: **********
```

Can I send all these in the URL using browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually, I don't think so... But you can always use postman/curl/insomnia

Comment: I wanted to use it as a string in a custom adapter for ViewPager in android. I had searched it but it seems it cant be done. I already use retrofit for this in android but I actually needed to use it as a single string. Anyways, thanks.